# Lucene: Commit interval during import of large data sets

Tags: optimization, indexing, lucene, commit

During indexing a large dataset, what are recommended commit strategies? I want to add ~ 10 Mio. docs to a newly created index, and I do not care about any intermediate results from the index (i.e. strict separation of indexing phase, then searching phase).

During indexing, I currently commit every 10.000 added documents, but I realized that this value is just some constant which I'm copying over and over from year old code, and I've never thought about choosing an optimal value.

My questions boil down to the following:

1. How are un-commited documents treated? Are they kept in memory?
2. How can I achieve optimal indexing performance? More commits vs. less commits?